# ros gazebo skipped loading plugin with error

Tags: ros, robotics

When I run my gazebo, I get the following error:

```
[ERROR] [1515141508.242475977]: Skipped loading plugin with error: XML Document '/opt/ros/kinetic/share/gmapping/nodelet_plugins.xml' has no Root Element. This likely means the XML is malformed or missing..
[ERROR] [1515141508.249164933]: Skipped loading plugin with error: XML Document '/opt/ros/kinetic/share/gmapping/nodelet_plugins.xml' has no Root Element. This likely means the XML is malformed or missing..
```

Even with the errors, gazebo seems to work fine but I would like to fix it just to be safe. However, I'm not sure what the error messages mean and how I can fix it.

Answer (score 0):

Can you verify if there is any "nodelet_plugins.xml" file is present in the /opt/ros/kinetic/share/gmapping directory?

Answer (score 0):

Add

> nodelet_plugins.xml

to your CMakeLists.txt file within your catkin_workspace

```
install( DIRECTORY launch
  FILES nodelet_plugins.xml
  DESTINATION ${CATKIN_PACKAGE_SHARE_DESTINATION}
)
```

Then do a `catkin_make` from your worksapce. The error should go away.

Note: Make sure /opt/ros/kinetic/share/gmapping/ has no *xml* files, just a folder called *cmake*. if there is a xml file, delete the file usng sudo